# Magento 2 : How to install Porto theme using command prompt in Localhost?

Tags: magento2, theme

How to install theme in magento2  using command prompt ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you chose/Apply theme for your currently active store from Backend ?

Comment: yes Vivek , I choose the theme in this path "content/design/edit/theme name"

Comment: Than Check frontend, Does any portion is affacted or still displaying Luma ?

Comment: please check the above image in the question description the theme shown like

Comment: Bro, Its already activated, You can start customing it OR You can Import your desired demo As mentioned in Documention. :)

Comment: In which location of admin panel we are  Import  desired demo

Comment: Dude, You first read documentation than ask here if you are having problem. Seems you didnt read it. :(

Comment: how to run this cmds"php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First install Default Magento-2 in Localhost.
2. Run the installation same as every installs of Magento.
3. Copy the all files of 'porto' theme into your root directory.
4. As of the local server, You have to install the Composer in your system.
5. Open composer or download from [Here](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
6. Run the following commands :

   ```
   php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

   php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"

   php composer-setup.php

   php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
   ```
7. Open command prompt by pressing **win+R**.
8. Run the following commands

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade

   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

   php bin/magento cache:clean

   php bin/magento cache:flush
   ```
9. Login to admin panel then check.

Answer (score 1):

- Enable Theme for Currently Active store.
- **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
- **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Comment: php bin/magento setup:upgrade

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`        i run the two commands

Comment: thank you vivek it is fine working my doubt is in magento1 we are using import static blocks and pages. But in magento2 how to import static blocks and pagges?

Comment: Check here for Blocks :
 https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-add-new-cms-blocks-magento-2.html

Same as Blocks for pages.

Comment: actually i am run this in localhost

Comment: please tell me vivek, how to run same commands in godaddy hosting

Comment: @Vivek, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231414/how-to-install-porto-paid-theme-properly-in-magento-2-2-4-of-godaddy-hosting

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 does not have this type of feature.

Only have the option to uninstall a theme.

> php -d memory_limit=10G bin/magento  theme:uninstall

You have to create own extension and build this feature this feature yourself.

Comment: Thank you Amit Bera. I copy the theme files and set the in content/design/config/theme name. But not calling properly

Comment: which theme have you used? May be you need to setup upgrade, some module related to our theme is not installed at your system. You should in install those. Also follow your theme doc also.Hope, it will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

To enable theme follow below steps:

> Step1: Put your porto theme in app/design directory.

copy Smartwave folder amd put in app/design directory. after your path would be `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto`.

> Step:2 Admin Configuration.

Then go to admin panel , `content > design > configuration` and then select your store and set there Porto theme.

> Step:3 setup upgrade

Do setup-upgrade and deploy.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

if magento verson is 2.2.* then use below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

After installation , do import step,  go to store configutation > porto setting panel and at last there is a tab installation. Import any one demo which you want and save it. !!

Comment: I didn't understand. How to run the commands sir

Comment: php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Add path before of php.exe file before  php bin/magento setup:upgrade command

Comment: By following this answer, porto doesn't show up in the theme selection menu, at least not in magento 2.3.1