# Magento cli no commands

Tags: magento2, cli

I installed a local Magento environment on XAMPP using composer. The database is also running on XAMPP (MySql). After the (web) setup i found out that the static files where not generated yet so I tried to run following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

I got the "There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace." error. After that I tried running cache:clear but I got the same error.

When I run

```
php bin/magento
```

I got 3 error message along with some normal info. The error message are the following:

```
[Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException] An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentosetupconsolecommandconfigsetcommand(alias: Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ConfigSetCommand).

[Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException] An exception was raised while creating "Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ConfigSetCommand"; no instance returned 

[Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException] Cannot read contents from file "C:\xampp\htdocs\magitas\app\code\duo\main\etc\module.xml" Warning!file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\magitas\app\code\duo\main\etc\module.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I have the correct user rights (otherwise my setup would not have run).

Thanks

Comment: please try: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186169/running-magento2-commands-in-windows-xampp/186178#186178

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution, and I'm a little embarrassed to be honest.
It was because the module.xml file was not created in one of my custom modules

Answer (score 0):

You can try xampp shell to execute commands for Magento.

Check here : [Magento 2 : How to install Porto theme using command prompt in Localhost?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230628/magento-2-how-to-install-porto-theme-using-command-prompt-in-localhost/230672#230672)

Comment: I am using the xampp shell it gives the same output unfortunately

Comment: Did you set enviroment variable for your PHP installation ?

Comment: I didn't but I checked and it's set to c:/xampp/php

Comment: I've edited my answer please follow accepted answer It will definitely solve your problems for CLI.

Comment: No it doesn't I get the "There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace."  error